# how to save or "stash" last commit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I often work on top of another person's commit (called "base" commit later) before it gets merged to the remote repository, usually it's a change in gerrit which I cherry-pick. When that person pushes new patchset to gerrit, I often need to replace my old "base" commit with new "base" commit, containing latest gerrit changes.

So let's say I have a local branch with **2** commits on it, the "base" commit and my commit on top of it. The way to accomplish what I want now is:

- save my current commit somewhere (i.e. `format-patch`)
- remove both commits from my local branch with `git reset --hard HEAD~2`
- cherry-pick a new version of "base" commit from gerrit
- reapply my previously saved commit again

By "commit" I mean an actual git commit, i.e. what you create by doing `git commit` or `git cherry-pick`.

Question: Is there a nice way to save the top commit on my branch, including commit message, and then restore it?

Comment: I've made a tentative answer based on the assumption that by "commit" you really mean "commit". How exactly do you "remove that person's commit from my local branch"?

Comment: Yes, by "commit" I mean whatever gets created on a branch when you do `git commit` or `git cherry-pick` :D By removing that commit I meant `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Yeah don't do that.   `Git reset --hard` means "I don't want these changes. Throw them away."  The very opposite of "save". See my answer.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I am doing that `git reset --hard` because I need to replace old "base" commit with new "base" commit, and I don't know any other way to do that other than removing old "base" commit it and applying new one. The word "save" in the topic refers to my commit which is on top of "base" commit.

Comment: No, I did understand. I'm telling you not to do it that way, that it's the wrong way to manage "changed changes" in git. If you update your question with the details you've added in these comments, then I'll update my answer with specific alternate steps that uses git correctly and will get you what you want.

Comment: I added more detailed description now, let's see how it goes.

Comment: updated my answer. this is a lot of time i can't afford, and for a question that is unlikely to help anyone but you.  But I like to help people. So let me ask you, honestly, were you looking for someone to do all this for you? Or would simple leads (i.e. you should learn how to use `git rebase`) been sufficient. Did you do any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to work with gerrit and this process works. I use the name *base* in the way you have used it in your question.

Say your branch looks like this

```
ID4 Your work 2
ID3 Your work 1
ID2 Base original version
ID1 The current head of master on the official branch
```

where the IDs are the Commit IDs you see when you do `git log --oneline`.

When you find out there is a new version of *base*, you can then do a **fetch** from gerrit, rather than a cherry-pick. (Or you can cherry-pick and then switch back to your branch.) You will then have a Commit ID for the new commit, let's call this ID5.

```
ID5 Base new version
```

You want to replace ID2 with ID5 in the list above. Because you have fetched ID5, you can easily to this via an interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i ID1
```

This will show you the todo-list of commits that are going to be applied (picked) on top of ID1 when you save the file and exit.

Simply replace ID2 with ID5 in this list. Save the file and exit.

A word of caution: Your commits (ID3 and ID4) that were created on top of ID2 may not apply cleanly on top of ID5 (because, for example, you alter things that depend on ID2, or conflict with ID5). Because of this, I would always recommend creating a backup branch before starting a rebase using the command

```
git branch backupXYZ
```

If your commits don't apply in the rebase and you cannot work out how to manually merge, you can then get back to where you were.

Answer (score 0):

A "commit" is by definition already *saved*. Using `git reset --hard HEAD~2` the way you are is essentially *unsaving* it, because there will no longer be a git ref pointing to it.[1]

You're basically employing a patch-based workfow instead of a branch-based on. (e.g. your `format-patch`). If you want to keep doing a patch-based workflow, you're steps are pretty much as easy as it can get.[2]

If you switch to the more modern and sophisticated branch-based workflow, you would use `git rebase` to, well, rebase any set of commits onto a new base.

I don't use Gerrit, so I don't know whether it directly supports branch-based workflows. I read somewhere it does support rebases. The quote below is [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_(software)). The first paragraph describes your process. The second paragraph *seems* to say that you're stuck with a patch-based workflow if you use Gerrit. **But I'm not sure.**  I think you should do the research. ;)

> Gerrit is a commit review tool. Developers amend individual commits in response to feedback; Gerrit tracks each version of each commit, allowing developers to view the differences between versions, and to rebase individual commits while keeping shared history in the review interface. Developers can pull individual commits (e.g.: using the 'cherry pick' option) and can push groups of related commits as a patch set.
>
> This **patch-based workflow is avoided** in favor of the pull request workflow used by several Git platforms such as GitHub and GitLab. In the pull request workflow **complete branches** are reviewed and merged. There are projects, such as Go (programming language) which use GitHub and Gerrit at the same time. Due to the process used by the Go team to sync GitHub pull requests to Gerrit, the pull request branch is squashed into a single commit. This loss of granular commit information in the squash is why the Go team recommends contributors to use their Gerrit instance.

#### how to use `git rebase` in your current approach

Replace your steps above with the following. I will assume the same example with two commits:

1. Move `head` to the commit prior to the "base commit": `git checkout HEAD~2`. You will be in a detached head state.
2. Cherry-pick a new version of "base" commit from gerrit onto it (as you did before).
3. Rebase the local branch on top of this, but only the tip that is your commit: `git rebase --onto head my-branch^ my-branch`.

If you had cherry-picked more commits from gerrit, or your local work has more than one commit, you will have to adjust `HEAD~2` in step 1 and `my-branch^` in step 3 accordingly.

---

[1] The commits aren't deleted, not yet at least, though they will when git eventually GC's them. They will continue to exist in the repo as orphaned commits. You can find them via `git reflog`, but you shouldn't not be doing that as part of a *normal* workflow. Reflogs are there for recovering from mistakes, not everyday use.

[2] You could use `git stash`, but that only works on uncommited changes. You *could* do this by `git reset <base commit>` which will essentially put all your work back in the uncommitted state, and then `git stash`, and then `git pop` on top of the updated base.

Comment: The thing is I don't have any branch with upstream commits locally. The commit is in gerrit and I cherry-pick it directly from there. Yes I can create a branch for every new version of the commit that the person uploaded to gerrit, but that would create a mess in my local branches... If rebase works somehow that's good, I just need a way to fit it somehow to work with gerrit :D

Comment: if you're afraid of using branches on git then you don't get git.